# overridden styles for flex module

Tags: apache-flex, module, styles

Can a flex module have styles different from the main application which loads the modules? Meaning... can I have a main set of styles for the application, and separate styles for each module.. with each of them rendering their own styles without disturbing the other at runtime?

My specific case:
The main application is developed by me... and the modules are developed by different people who want to contribute to the main application. I want to provide some way for each of the module developers to have their own styles for their modules, without touching the main application or its styles.

Answer (score 1):

Try loading your modules into separate application domain (which is not a child of the application domain of your main application).

Comment: Yes, that should do the trick according to http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7f8c.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7e6d

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can do what you're asking (although I'd like to know if I'm wrong), as in say have two CSS files one for a module and one for the main app.

What you could do is inside the CSS instead of declaring a single `Canvas` style do something like:

```
Canvas.mainapp {
...
}

Canvas.module {
...
}
```

Then inside your module when you declare a `Canvas` set its style to `module` and inside the main apps whenever you declare a `Canvas` set its style to `mainapp`

That would do.

Comment: Thanks for the response kenneth. In my case, the main application is developed by me... and the modules are developed by different people who want to contribute to the main application. 
I want to provide some way for each of the module developers to have their own styles for their modules without touching the main application or its styles. 
Getting a little tricky now? :)

Comment: That CSS syntax is not supported in flex 3 unfortunately.